# Call menu clicked event as a script, but the menu name at runtime is dynamic

Tags: events, dynamic, menu, execute

I have a Datawindow Grid in a window I've created and one column of this DW has as its data, different menu paths that are the same of the menus and submenus I have created. The point is that when I double-click on every DW row, I want to execute the clicked event of the different menu path that is stored as data in each row.
For example the first row is "m_epith_frame.m_parms_su.m_poi.m_poi_ergast", the second is "m_appl_frame.m_1_sb.m_2_sb" etc. 
I know that when in scripts, I write  m_epith_frame.m_parms_su.m_poi.m_poi_ergast.Clicked(), it triggers the Clicked event of this menu item and for example opens a form...
So how can I click each row and trigger the clicked event for every menu path of each row?
It is, I suppose, a dynamic event call problem, but I can not find any solution..

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can recurse menus to build up a string array of the menu paths. At the same time build up an array of the menu items and assign the `menuitem` object to this using the same array index number as for the strings. Don't use create, just assign the `menuitem` to the array.

When someone clicks on a row, find the index of the path in the string array, then trigger a click event on the menu item array using the same index.

The menu item array holds pointers to the real menu items in the menu, so it's the same as clicking on the menu option, e.g you can code

```
im_menuitems[li_menuindex].Triggerevent (Clicked!)
```

and if this is `m_epith_frame.m_parms_su.m_poi.m_poi_ergast` that is what is clicked.